# Velocity template - message key #msg

Tags: java, spring-boot, velocity

I have email template .vm which contains msg with message key from messages_en.properties:

```
#msg("email-ePwdReminder-salutation")
```

and created the velocity context as follow:

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("email-ePwdReminder-salutation",messageSource.getMessage("email.ePwdReminder.salutation",null,locale));
Merge the template with the context to generate the HTML body
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

Replace with logic to fetch the correct template
Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate(templateName);
template.process();
template.merge(context, writer);

String htmlBody = writer.toString();
```

**#msg** seems not be a predefined directive for velocity engine, so how can I create a custom directive **#msg** and be able to replace **email.ePwdReminder.salutation** variable in the email template.